# Default external file path for java application packed in jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, path

I am trying to externally run a Java Application, that everyone up to today runs directly from netbeans, this application accesses some files, and the path is hardcoded (this is not something I am allowed to modify) as example/path/file.txt, as it is right now, example is a folder in the root of the netbeans project folder (i.e. alongside dist, src, and those) and the application runs fine from inside netbeans, so it seems that when a path is hardcoded without a leading / it is taken from the netbeans project root folder. However when running this application as a jar, it does not find these files, I have tried moving this required files to dist (the same folder where the jar is located) and it also doesn't work, so my question is: What path does a .jar look for files when the path is not coded using a leading /?

I have no previous experience with this because I wouldn't usually hardcode a file path like that, but as I said in this particular case this is something I am not allowed to change.

Comment: The system usually uses the current directory as the root if there's no leading /.  Post the code that loads the file if you need more help.  We'll probably also need the contents of the manifest file, and a directory listing of the Jar file.

Comment: I can't post any of that code, but anyways, it is as you said (and as I expected at the begining) it takes the same directory of the jar as the root. The problem ended up being that the person who coded this disregarded capitalization in paths, I suppose always using this in Windows, so the exact same application runs fine on Windows but crashes due to files not found on Linux (where capitalization matters) independently whether it is being run from netbeans or straight as a jar.